# Could not broadcast input array from shape (3,200,200,3) into shape (3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

Im trying to use pre-trained model for my project;

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator


datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
rotation_range=40,
width_shift_range=0.2,
height_shift_range=0.2,
shear_range=0.2,
zoom_range=0.2,
horizontal_flip=True,
fill_mode='nearest')


test_img = train_dataset[1]
img = image.img_to_array(test_img)  # convert image to numpy arry
img = img.reshape((1,) + img.shape)  # reshape image

i = 0

for batch in datagen.flow(img, save_prefix='test', save_format='jpeg'):  # this loops runs forever until we break, saving images to current directory with specified prefix
    plt.figure(i)
    plot = plt.imshow(image.img_to_array(batch[0]))
    i += 1
    if i > 4:  # show 4 images
        break

plt.show()
```

I get this error when I run code above
could not broadcast input array from shape (3,200,200,3) into shape (3)

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-546c359868af> in <module>
     14 # pick an image to transform
     15 test_img = train_dataset[1]
---> 16 img = image.img_to_array(test_img)  # convert image to numpy arry
     17 img = img.reshape((1,) + img.shape)  # reshape image
     18 

~\miniconda3\envs\tensorflownew\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py in img_to_array(img, data_format, dtype)
     73     if dtype is None:
     74         dtype = backend.floatx()
---> 75     return image.img_to_array(img, data_format=data_format, dtype=dtype)
     76 
     77 

~\miniconda3\envs\tensorflownew\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\utils.py in img_to_array(img, data_format, dtype)
    297     # or (channel, height, width)
    298     # but original PIL image has format (width, height, channel)
--> 299     x = np.asarray(img, dtype=dtype)
    300     if len(x.shape) == 3:
    301         if data_format == 'channels_first':

~\miniconda3\envs\tensorflownew\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     81 
     82     """
---> 83     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     84 
     85 

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3,200,200,3) into shape (3)
```

My target size is as follows

```
train_dataset = train.flow_from_directory('MNIST_data/train', target_size = (200,200), batch_size = 3, class_mode = 'binary')  

validation_dataset = train.flow_from_directory('MNIST_data/validation', target_size = (200,200), batch_size = 3, class_mode = 'binary')
```

Should I add a transformer or is there another problem with the code?

Comment: Can you add the complete error traceback?

Comment: I added the complete error traceback.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this code? ie. Expected Output

Comment: The code where I receive the error is TensorFlow's  code for increasing model accuracy, it rotates the image to better the pattern detection